# Can you make vim wait for a command process to finish before executing the next command?

Tags: vimrc

I have a Perl test script. I a) use [`Vimux`](https://github.com/benmills/vimux) to show the output of the script in a new pane. Once the script is done with its output, I want to b) immediately hide the pane in preparation for c) pulling up the output of the test script (saved in a file) in a new buffer where I can see it nicely syntaxed highlighted with vim just how I like it.

Here is the vim code for for parts a) and b) of my task:

`nnoremap <F7> :w<CR>:call VimuxRunCommand("prove --normalize -v -j 10 -a test.tgz " . bufname('%'))<CR><bar> :silent !tmux kill-pane -a -t 0<CR>`

The problem is that the pane closes immediately before anything gets output to it. I want to wait for my `prove` command to finish executing before I run the next vim command. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use sleep command to wait. Instead of `:call`, you can store the value returned bt the VimuxRunCommand and evaluate it with a true/false criteria and close it.

Comment: So let's say I sleep for 5 seconds but the script runs 10 seconds. There's no way to make that work, right?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
nnoremap <F7> :w <bar>
  \ call VimuxRunCommand("prove --normalize -v -j 10 -a test.tgz " . bufname('%')) <bar>
  \ echo 'press any key' <bar>
  \ call getchar() <bar>
  \ silent !tmux kill-pane -a -t 0<CR>
```